# How to set a "main field" of a layer in QGIS interface (instead UUID)?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, qfield, search

I have a layer inserted in QGIS.

When I select/interact various elements together, to distinguish them the interface offers me grouping by UUID which is the primary key.

Of course I want UUID to remain the primary key, but the question is if it is possible to show as "search key" (in the attached case) another more understandable field as an alternative to UUID (even if it is not a primary key and if there would be duplicates).

For example, "Post Office" for the first and "Restaurant" for the second in this case, attributes set in a "Type" field.

This would also be useful in using Qfield (I convert the project).

Thanks

[image: Set another field than UUID.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the layer properties (right click on it then properties...) there in the Display tab you may set the display name and choose any field you want, you could even use an expression to fully personalize the display name (for exemple you may want to display both the type and the uuid or an adresse  to differentiate between element of the same type)